# Why the degree of the joint axis, read in gazebo::ModelPlugin accumulates automatically?

Tags: gazebo

I have a joint axis within the SDF model. After launching the model in Gazebo (version 11.13.0), I use the `gazebo::ModelPlugin` to read the angle of the joint axis. However, even though the joint remains stationary, the angle continues to increase in one direction.
As shown in data below, and the time stamp between two samples is 100ms.

```
<joint name="steer_joint" type="revolute">
  <parent>g29_wheel_base_link</parent>
  <child>g29_steer_link</child>
  <axis>
    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
  </axis>
</joint>
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
void onWorldFrame() {         
    gazebo::physics::JointPtr joint = this->model->GetJoint("steer_joint");
    double degree = joint->Position(0)
```

This is how the output looks like:

```
data: -2266.800537109375
---
data: -2266.9033203125
---
data: -2267.024169921875
---
data: -2267.141357421875
---
data: -2267.2587890625
---
data: -2267.379638671875
---
data: -2267.4931640625
---
data: -2267.592041015625
---
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.